# swift: change image in specific cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have `collectionView`. I want to change image in specific cell.

I use this code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell

    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 5{
        cell.cover.image = UIImage(named: "sfsdf.png")
    }
}
```

But images changes in all cells. How to fix it?

Comment: You need to do add after your `if`: `else { cell.cover.image = nil }` because cells are reused. Each time you change a property according to some logic (if etc.) you need to do the reverse action in the other case.

Comment: you need to put code in else part same opposite add in if condition.

Comment: get help of your datasource array

Comment: Also use `func prepareForReuse(){ self.cover.image = }` in your cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of dequeuing

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let myCell = cell as! MasterViewCell

    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 5{
        myCell.cover.image = UIImage(named: "sfsdf.png")
    }
    else {
        myCell.cover.image = UIImage(named: "other.png") // supply other image or access from model array 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add image of other cells in else part.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell
        if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 5 {
            cell.cover.image = UIImage(named: "sfsdf.png")
        } else {
            cell.cover.image = UIImage(named: "Other.png")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing the prototype cell. So you should provide else case to prevent the change in all other cells.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell

    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 5{
        cell.cover.image = UIImage(named: "sfsdf.png")
    }
    else 
    {
        cell.cover.image = UIImage(named: "default.png") //change default.png with the name of your image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` reuses it's cell for displaying. So the same cell will appear as next. We have to configure each one.

Always write `else` condition for `if` statement when we change cell configuration.

```
if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 5 {
    cell.cover.image = UIImage(named: "sfsdf.png")
} else {
    cell.cover.image = nil // OR use placeholder image. UIImage(named: "placeholder")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using reusable cell so you need to set default image.

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell

     cell.cover.image = nil // OR set default image

     if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 5{
         cell.cover.image = UIImage(named: "sfsdf.png")
     }
}
```